# Append div to hidden elements in Angular using jquery

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this div

```
 <div class="col-md-4 solution" *ngIf="show">

 </div>
```

which is by default hidden now on button click i want to show that div and append another div to the `solution div` hide and show is working but append is not working for elements that are hidden.

```
   this.show=true;
   let area = $(".solution");
   let Detail = `<div class="class-1"> 
        <p>Text<p>
        </</div>`;
    area.append(Detail);
```

Any solution to append the div. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `.class` selector selects all elements with the specific class.

`area`  is a collection of elements

```
 var _that=this;
 setTimeout(function(){      
   if($(".solution") && _that.show == true){// If solution div is visible/shown
    let area = $('.solution:first')
    let Detail = `<div class="class-1"> 
    <p>Text<p>
    </</div>`;
    area.append(Detail); 
 }}, 200);
```

you need to append over the targeted div by element at `index` .

Comment: Thanks i tried it but it is not working `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'append')` when element is not hidden initially then my above code in question is working if it is hidden and i make it visible on button click then it is not getting appended

Comment: because its hidden so you have to append only if it is shown on UI

Comment: i was trying to append after `this.show=true;` that will show `solution div` on UI

Comment: i tried this also but the same issue, and `id` in place of `class` is also not working eg : `let area = $("#solution");` the same button which is showing the div is used to append also